# datagridview How to hide header border for specific column vb.net

Tags: datagridview, header, border

How to hide header border for specific column ??

[image]

```
  e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None
```

Just removed border for content cell